# why intellij deploy application to tomcat webapp folder by default?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

intellij always deploy the application to tomcat folder by default, why? 
the server.xml in the ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.2/tomcat/Unnamed_ds_workspace/conf is

```
Host name="localhost" appBase="/Users/luganlin/workspace/ccshome/finance/apache-tomcat-7.0.90/webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="false">
```

as you can see, the appBase always points to the tomcat webapp folder, which leads to when I deploy more than one application with the same context path, it will be mixed together. 
btw, there is another server.xml.0 in the same folder, seems the default one with correct value:

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

intellij version: 2018.2.2
os version: macOS Sierra 10.12

Answer (score 0):

IDE sets the `docBase` path in `$CATALINA_BASE#\conf\Catalina\localhost\<app_context_path>.xml` file to tell Tomcat the path name to the web application archive file. So it creates each such file with `docBase` pointing to the folder of the artifact that you have selected for deployment to the server.